# Random black screen on Windows 8.1 Machine

Tags: windows-8

I am running a Toshiba Notebook with Windows 8.1 and randomly I will get a black screen while running the computer or I will try and boot and the screen will remain black but the machine is running. While using the computer, the machine and CPU are still active there is simply no response and no display. I have plugged it into an external display with no trouble. Anyone else experienced this or have a solution that may solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a virus but rather a problem with the graphics card and its drivers and their interaction with Windows. It used to be fairly common and normally happens when the machine comes out of sleep/standby.

I suspect - but cannot prove - that it has something to do with the graphics memory not being reset correctly. I've seen it on many laptops from Toshiba, Acer and others. It does not appear to be such a problem under W8 as it was under W7. In fact, I haven't seen it for a while now on newer laptops.

You might try to find some alternative video card drivers (both downgrades as well as newer versions) to see if there is one that is better.

Comment: So the first step would be an upgrade to the graphics card drivers? Any recommendations on where to begin? I'm a Mac and Linux guy so a little out of my element with this.

Comment: First check the Toshiba site by preference. Then look at what graphics chipset you have and go to the graphics vendors site. Sometimes a downgrade can help too.